# ruby on rails: path and URL helpers don't work with singular names

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, I'm trying to create my first application. I'm using resourceful routes for instance 'subjects':

```
resource :subjects do
    member do
      get :delete
    end
end
```

I've created controller SubjectsController and views for its methods. In index view I'm trying to create a link to show view like that:

```
link_to("Show", subject_path(1))
```

but it returns the error:

```
undefined method `subject_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc820551488>:0x007fc8229468c0>
Did you mean?  subjects_path
```

The same thing with helper 'new_subject_path'. But what weird new_subject**s**_path doesn't give any error and creates a proper link. What's wrong with my app? Should I use plurals for path helpers???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is because you are using the `resource` singular, when you mean to use the `resources` plural version. Try changing your routes to:

```
resources :subjects do
  member do
    get :delete
  end
end
```

And you should find you get the expected rails url helper methods.

The convention is when you expect to have several items of the resources existing, to use the plural versions `resources :subjects`, but when you expect only a single entity to exist use the singular `resource :subject` which will create different routes and helpers that don't require an `id` param.

Comment: Thanks!!! Yes, you're right, I meant resources. For newbie difference is really slight, but your answer cleared everything up.

Comment: Thats great! If it helped maybe give it an upvote? and perhaps choose the answer that was posted first instead of the one that copied it after lol. But the main thing is your problem is solved! good luck and happy coding!

Comment: unfortunately I cannot do upvote yet, I don't have enough reputation. Thanks for you help anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you want singular resource, change `:subjects` to `:subject`.

```
resource :subject do
  member do
    get :delete
  end
end
```

Or use full `resources` instead of `resource`:

```
resources :subjects do
  member do
    get :delete
  end
end
```

With either change, you'll be able to use `subject_path` helper. But with the first one, you cannot pass in a ID. If you need that, use the second one.

Comment: thanks, that helped!! I really meant resources not resource. Silly misspelling